# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

When i want to install xgboost , i got this error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_0/x_mtxr8s5lg9jy8nsdn23hlw0000gn/T/pip-build-fu5e_g5v/xgboost/
```

---

i use this [instruction](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-osx) for installing xgboost

and when i use brew install gcc --without-multilib for installing `gcc-6.x.x` but the OS sticks in `make bootstrap` section :

[image]